# Excel VBA TextToColumns pushing text up and overwriting header

Tags: excel, vba

This code is a sliver of my main code so I know it is missing a line for, say, calling out the sheet, but I got that covered.

I've narrowed down the problem to this but I don't understand excel enough to figure out -why-. I assume it has to do with the array but not sure. Basically, what happens is I run this and it takes the column of data and pushes it up 1 row, overwriting the header with the value in EN2. The last cell in the column doesn't go blank, but copies itself. It is like the last value is copied and pasted at the bottom but instead of overwriting the cell, pushes ALL the cell data up one row. Weird.

```
Sub RoutineTest()
Range(Range("EN2"), Range("EN2").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range( _
        "BurnData[[#Headers],[est_po_place]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier _
        :=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:= _
        False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 3) _
        , TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Hope someone can help me figure out why.

Comment: Where does this **Range("BurnData[[#Headers],[est_po_place]]")** point to in the document?

Comment: I'm guessing this has to do with your headers being included in your text to columns. Perhaps try starting on Range("EN3")?

Comment: That doesn't work. I have tried so many ways to fix this issue, I am nearly just done with it all and resigning myself to handling it manually after the fact. If I put EN3, it jumps up 2 rows, so I tried to put in EN1 and it worked kinda. The data has blanks at some points in it, meaning the xlDown only goes to the next piece of data. 

The overall problem with all of this is I was using Columns("EN:EN").Select instead. But this causes the table to be extended down thousands of rows, randomly. Sometimes 50k, sometimes 100k+. Then I have to resize the table and delete data EVERY TIME.

Comment: I tried to keep that code but find new code to just resize the table, nothing I found would work. No errors, just nothing happens. Then I tried to delete all rows below the last cell in a particular column. No effect. No errors, just nothing happened. I have no idea anymore.

I don't necessarily care about my code being all short and neat and tidy. I'd much rather it just -work- first. I'll worry about it being efficient later.

Comment: And VBasic2008, BurnData is the worksheet I am on testing this. est_po_place is the name of the header that has dates under it. This macro converts the dates to a Short Date form i need for other formulas.

Comment: Just FYI, I indirectly fixed this entire issue by using the EN1 option above then adding code to delete all blank rows (some formula fields have like #ref! in them but most are blank) below my data based around a column that always has something in every cell. This way it deletes all superfluous rows, cells and deleting the rows in a table shortens said table. TBH I half-expected Excel to maintain table size even after deleting rows involving it.